# Highcharts - Donut chart - Sections joining as puzzle

Tags: svg, highcharts

I have this highcharts donut chart:
[image]

It's a SVG generated by highcharts and I was wondering if is possible to get the joining of it's sections to be displayed as a puzzle, something like this:
[image]

If it helps in any way, I can attach the SVG code of the two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behaviour is not supported in Highcharts by default, but possible by some customization. You can for example wrap `drawPoints` method and modify generated SVG graphic.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    const chart = this.chart;
    const point = this.points[0];

    this.points.forEach(point => {
      // M, A, L, A, Z
      const pathArray = point.graphic.pathArray;
      const width = point.shapeArgs.r - point.shapeArgs.innerR;
      const halfWidth = width / 2;
      const size = 10;
      const halfSize = size / 2;
      // M, A, L, A, Z
      const cutX1 = pathArray[1][6];
      const cutY1 = pathArray[1][7];
      const cutX2 = pathArray[2][1];
      const cutY2 = pathArray[2][2];

      const x1 = pathArray[3][6];
      const y1 = pathArray[3][7];
      const x2 = pathArray[0][1];
      const y2 = pathArray[0][2];

      pathArray[2] = [
        'L',
        cutX1 + (point.half ? size : -size), cutY1 + (point.half ? halfWidth : -halfWidth),
        cutX2, cutY2
      ];
      pathArray.splice(4, 0, [
        'L',
        x2 - size, y2 + (point.half ? -halfWidth : halfWidth),
        x2, y2
      ]);

      point.graphic = chart.renderer.path().attr({
        d: pathArray
      }).add(point.series.group);
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nq36b4jo/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the instructions to go forward.